# Tarring a series of files/directories without "." as a parent directory?

Tags: centos7, tar, gnome

I am generating a .tar.gz file with the following command.

```
tar cfhpz archive.tar.gz -C /lots/of/subdirectories/files .
```

/lots/of/subdirectories/files contains a directory structure that is something like:

```
+
|-- bin/
|-- dist/
|-- lib/
```

And so on.

My end goal from running this command is to have a .tar.gz that contains a directory structure exactly like the one within /lots/of/subdirectories/files -- with no additional parent directories.

Using the command I specified, everything *appears* to be structured exactly how I want when I view the archive using Ark or the Archive Mounter. However, when I view the archive using GNOME Archive Manager, it shows that all of the files/folders are actually in a subdirectory called "." like so:

```
+
|-- .
    |-- bin/
    |-- dist/
    |-- lib/
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the "." subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command you call the directory `.`, which is linked to the directory that your are in. The `.` directory is a real directory, it just happens to have all the same continence as the directory that `.`, its self, is in. For example, when you run a script with `./script.sh`, what you are doing is the same as if from a other position on the file system you gave the command `/path/to/script.sh`. It's a convention in Bash to use the `./` when you are running an executable file from local directory. Alternatively you could run a script `bash script.sh`

So, when you run

```
tar cfhpz archive.tar.gz -C /lots/of/subdirectories/files .
```

it resolves to `./all-the-stuff-in-the-directory`. What you want is to take all the files in the directory, and not look at the them as a subdirectory of `./`. To do this, you want to use the wild-card, or regular expression, charter `*`, which matches to everything.

```
tar cfhpz archive.tar.gz -C /lots/of/subdirectories/files *
```

For example, if I run `echo ~/Documents/*`

```
/home/seamus/Documents/2013 /home/seamus/Documents/2014 /home/seamus/Documents/2015 /home/seamus/Documents/2016 /home/seamus/Documents/2017 /home/seamus/Documents/2018 /home/seamus/Documents/2019
```

What we get echo-ed back are all the continence of the directory and no `./`, `../` or other hidden files.

The difference with KDE Ark and Gnome file Archive Manager is that Ark is making the inference that the `./` is probably just a redirect to the folder contains. This differs form Grome which is probably running something similar to `ls` on the file structure, where it actually lets you walk the the file sturcture.

Comment: Thank you, and excellent explanation as to why this is occurring!

I do want to add that when I tried this out, it did require me to be within the /lots/of/subdirectories/files as a working directory for * to resolve to the correct set of files. Fortunately, for my use case, changing the working directory is a non-issue.

Comment: You can just add it to the file path; `/lots/of/subdirectories/files/*`.